# Code acting crazy

Tags: c

I just wrote a test code that looks like the first iteration of a max heap. But it has a run time error. The second if condition is acting crazy; it is not supposed to be executed but somehow it does.

Expected o/p: `8 5 3 7 2`
Current o/p: `3 8 5 7 2`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[]={5,8,3,7,2};

void printArray()
{
    printf("\nStatus of the array\n");
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("[%d]",a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void swap(int x,int y)
{
//  printf("%d %d",a[x],a[y]);
    a[x]=a[x]+a[y];
    a[y]=a[x]-a[y];
    a[x]=a[x]-a[y];
}

void maxHeap(int i)
{
    int largest=i,right=0,left=0;

    left=(2*i)+1;
    right=(2*i)+2;

    if(a[left] > a[i])
        largest=left;

    printf("L=%d R=%d",left,right);

    if(a[right] > a[i]);
    {
        printf("\na[right]=%d a[i]=%d",a[right],a[i]);
        largest=right;
    }
    if(largest != i)
        swap(largest,i);
}

void main()
{
    printArray();
    maxHeap(0);
    printArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(a[right] > a[i]); <--- oops remove this semicolon
{
    printf("\na[right]=%d a[i]=%d",a[right],a[i]);
    largest=right;
}
```